# Three.js THREE.Matrix4 find the face of cube showed

Tags: three.js

I'm doing tests with Three.js, i create a cube obj and I found the location of the cube

```
    scene.updateMatrixWorld(true);
    var position = new THREE.Vector3();
    position.getPositionFromMatrix( cube.matrixWorld );

    console.log(cube.matrixWorld);

    console.log(position);
    alert(position.x + ',' + position.y + ',' + position.z);
```

but i need **find the face of cube showed**.

EDIT ::sorry for the lack of clarity::

i have a dice i find the face for calculate value, independently from the camera, but with reference floor

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to add more information to your question. How do you want to find the face? Using a cube, there can be 1 to 3 faces shown depending on camera position. If you want to get the face when clicking on an object, check out the three.js cpu picking example and read up on "raycaster".

If you want to know about what face you are looking at, you need to have the camera viewing vector (there is a thread on here on how to get it) and then check against the face normals using a dot product. So to say: dot-product of camera view vector and face normal. If it is below 90 degrees, the face is visible by the camera....and so on.

Comment: hi , i read the thread like "need to have the camera viewing vector"
but i need the face respect of the floor , independently from the camera,i find the dice face opposite to that resting on the floor

Comment: sorry, i don't understand what you are saying and I don't understand what you want to achieve. Please try to be more precise and update your question above!!

Answer (score 0):

this is the example :

http://www.webgl.it/tests/diceGravity.html
I'm trying to find a way to get the the value of nut
when the nut stops .